# systemd won't start service

Tags: 18.04, systemd, jupyter

I am trying to start a jupyter notebook service using systemd with the following service unit file in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/run/jupyter.pid

ExecStart=/MountPoint/ssd01/environment/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook 
--config=/home/jayden.lxy/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

User=jayden.lxy
WorkingDirectory=/home/jayden.lxy
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I put the file in /usr/lib/systemd/system and execute the following command

```
sudo systemctl enable jayden.jupyter.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart jayden.jupyter.service
```

but it gives me the Exec format error. 
Anyone to help?

Comment: What is the result of `file /MountPoint/ssd01/environment/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook`? exec format error sounds like architecture mismatch.

Comment: /MountPoint/ssd01/environment/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook is an executable that i am trying to run here. I am able to run the same command without using systemd.

Comment: And what does `journalctl -xe` say?

Comment: It says -- The user manager instance for user 1322604 has been started. All services queued
-- for starting have been started. Note that other services might still be starting
-- up or be started at any later time.

Comment: So I am thinking perhps your systemd script should be a daemon or forking or oneshort please see https://superuser.com/questions/1274901/systemd-forking-vs-simple/1274913 Run yoyur script manually to see which of those types it conforms to the  adjust as need...

Comment: In my case, the service type should be simple. it continues running after execution and I need to ctrl-c to stop it.

Comment: I found a way around this problem but doesn't explain the reason why the normal way doesn't work. I added my command to /etc/rc.local and ran my command as rc-local service, then everything worked. However, I still don't get it why I can't start my own service.